# Threshold scaling along a straight line

Tags: math, cluster-analysis, distance, normalization, scaling

I am currently trying to find points between two clusters. For this I found the orientation in which the clusters lie another by calculating a straight line from both cluster centers. Based on this I calculate distances between data points and this line and want to find points with a distance smaller than a threshold. However, this threshold is based on each cluster separately. Lets assume I got T1 as threshold for one cluster and T2 as threshold for the other cluster. Now I want to calculate if a point lies within a distance smaller than these thresholds based on the distance travelled along the line. My idea was to find the point on the line closest to the data point and calculate a new threshold based on the distance traveled along the line. How would I do this?
Kind regards